# input in a div that has the haslayout attribute in ie has a "margin-left"

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

a simple html page .if you run it in **IE**(my version is **7**).
you will find the input have a "margin-left"(size is 15px).
but if you delete the (*zoom:1),we should use it to trigger the haslayout in ie,the "margin-left" disappear.

so  that is why???

```
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
            body,div,input{margin:0;padding:0;}
            .div-inline{display:inline-block;*display:inline;*zoom:1;border:1px solid red;}
            .marginLeft-15{margin-left:15px;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="marginLeft-15">
            <div class="div-inline"><input type="text" id="proxy_unuse_address"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `display:inline-block;` triggers the hasLayout too(according to [this page](http://www.brunildo.org/test/InlineBlockLayout.html)), so why dont you just remove the `*display:inline;*zoom:1;` style completely, it should work...

Comment: no  you are wrong.the block element trigger the haslayout need use "*display:inline;*zoom:1;",please confirm it

Comment: or .div-inline{display:inline-block;}.div-inline{display:inline-block;}

Comment: so the `.div-inline{display:inline-block;border:1px solid red;}` style doesnt work for you?